# Spik3r wheels move but the spik3r itself doesn't

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

Our [Spik3r](https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/build-a-robot/spik3r)'s wheels move but the Spik3r itself does not move. Please see the picture of the back of the vehicle - is it somehow incorrectly built?

[image]

Comment: So the motor-powered wheels roll freely when you hold the model up? And when you put it down on the floor it won't move? The insect-like legs are designed to be moved by the forward motion of the model. Check that these two leg sections are not blocked.

Comment: That wheel with the blue connector through it...does that rest on the ground? Because it cannot turn...

Answer (score 5):

You just need to flip the small motor the other way!
[image]

Comment: The motor is indeed mounted upside down, which could result in the grey parts sticking out far enough that the wheels do not touch the ground anymore.