# SPIK3R can't even hold itself

Tags: ev3

The [**SPIK3R**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qytmWI_XGPI) does not move properly. When I remove the legs and depend on the wheels it works like it should: goes forward when I make it go forward, and turns when I make it go backward. I did not make [this mistake](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/11266/15028) and I am certain that it is built correctly. When I try to make it go forward with it's legs on it just wobbles around for a few seconds and then falls on it's rear end, then the legs pop off.

Also, the front and back legs are pointing straight to the ground because of [this part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32192) and I'm thinking that I should replace it with [**this** part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32034#T=C) to give it more flexibility.

Should I do that? Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Could it be that the positions of the legs are not synchronised properly? Can you post a picture or a video of your built model or of the malfunctioning behaviour?

Comment: Whenever I get the chance, I will.

Comment: Did you get a chance? It's quite hard to answer this without seeing it in action.

Comment: @Mast No, not yet. For now just let this question sit here and do nothing until I do upload of picture or something. But it is not very likely anyway...